# eclipse m2e cannot find dependency of hibernate-core at current version

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I am using eclipse 4.3 with the maven plugin (m2e).

I added this dependency to my project's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the dependency from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.5.Final

But the m2e-plugin says:

```
Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.5.Final
```

If I change the version to `4.2.3` everything works fine.

I have tried (multiple times) to update and rebuild the index of the central-maven-repository.

Any ideas? TIA!

Edit: 
My maven-repositories (in eclipse):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running `mvn -U dependency:resolve` from the command line? Are you sure that your Maven installation is pulling directly from Central and not from some proxy Nexus server?

Comment: @chrylis I have tried `mvn -U dependency:resolve`. I am not sure about some proxy-server. I have added a screenshot of my maven-repos in eclipse. Should I try to delete the "Apache Nexus"?

Comment: No, don't go deleting repositories. If you run with `mvn -X`, does it give you more information about the error (like it's getting a 404 somewhere)?

Comment: @chrylis I am using the eclipse-plugin and I am not sure how to run it with `mvn -X`. But the plugin shows in the error-log: `The POM for org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.5.Final is missing, no dependency information available`. It shows like the dependency is corrupt. Am I right?

Comment: Run Maven from the command line for better output. See if you have a corrupt POM for 4.2.5.Final in your local repository and delete it if so. If there's nothing there, it sounds like Maven is getting a 404, and `-X` will give you debug output to figure out where the missing file is.

Comment: That's it. There was a `4.2.5.Final` in my local repository. I deleted it, rebuilt the index (of the local repository) and now it works. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by chrysilis in the comments the problem was an corrupt package in my local repository. After deleting that, everything works fine.